# Настройка logback.xml для логирования в файл

Tags: java, log4j, logback

У меня задача настороить `logback.xml` так, чтобы каждый день создавался новый файл `log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`, и все что касается уровня `DEBUG` писалось туда. Но вместо этого, у меня получается один файл `log.log`, в который пишется все без разделения по датам. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне поправить мой `logback.xml` так, что бы если файла с текущей датой нет, то он его создавал и писал туда, а если есть, то писал в существующий. Спасибо.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>log/log.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <FileNamePattern>log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.codingpedia" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Попробуйте изменить строку `<FileNamePattern>log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>` на `<FileNamePattern>log/log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>`, чтобы было сопоставимо с значением тега `File`.

Comment: @Alex Chermenin да решил поменяв как вы сказали только <File> вообще убрал похоже он не обязателен.